# «Давайте» — разговорное?

Tags: выбор-слов

Учитель русского языка при проверке сочинения-рассуждения (15.1 из КИМа ОГЭ) утверждает, что писать «Давайте докажем истинность данного высказывания, обратившись к представленному тексту» неправильно (конкретно — слово «давайте»). Аргументирует она это тем, что им где-то там на семинаре сказали, что это надо считать за ошибку. Считаю это чушью, но никак не могу доказать. Что можете сказать на этот счет?

Answer (score 4):

Это слово *не может* принадлежать исключительно области устной речи, но в некоторых текстах оно может оказаться неуместным. По своему смыслу это обращение с призывом к кому-то что-то совместно сделать или чем-то заняться (общий смысл: "давайте - мы с вами - поступим так"). Оно уместно в переписке людей в достаточной мере знакомых и либо с равными возможностями, либо когда адресат ниже по положению. Уместно доверительное обращение с таким призывом и при изложении письменного материала в форме лекции, ведь на лекции в обычной аудитории время от времени так обращаются к слушателям, привлекая их внимание к важному доказательству, к участию в обсуждении и т. п. Но можно понять, почему в сочинении, фактически *адресованном преподавателям*, такой призыв может прозвучать невежливо: "Давайте..." не подходит для обращения ученика к учителю, да и к какому совместному с автором действию этот призыв относится? Возможно, в примере из вопроса нужно было просто начать приведение доказательств со слова "Докажем...". "Попробуем доказать", "рассмотрим" - тоже устоявшиеся формы рассуждения во множественном числе; они ни к каким действиям не призывают, а только констатируют, что помимо автора есть читатель или слушатель, который при этом присутствует.

Comment: Напоминает гадание на кофейной гуще. Что-то я сомневаюсь, что учитель мог так рассуждать. Тем более, что ему могли такое выдать "на семинаре". Хорошо бы автора услышать с подробным изложением позиции учителя.

Comment: *Оно уместно в переписке людей в достаточной мере знакомых и либо с равными возможностями, либо когда адресат ниже по положению.* - никак не могу согласиться, что *только* так. Т. е., если буквально вас понимать, когда дипломат с трибуны скажет что-то типа "Давайте бороться за мир во всем мире" - это будет ошибкой?

Comment: Я здесь говорю о письменном жанре и конкретно - о переписке. Вряд ли может так обратиться напр. подследственный к прокурору ("давайте, я начну сотрудничать, а вы мне..."), но коллеги-прокуроры, занимающиеся общей проблемой (как поступить) - почему бы и нет?

Comment: *"давайте, я начну сотрудничать, а вы мне..."* - ну мало ли **как нельзя** в прокуратуру обращаться?! Тут вопрос этикетный, к стилистике мало отношения имеет. Да и не тот смысл вы вкладываете в давайте. Это у вас торг получается, а смысл может быть совсем другой. "Давайте вместе подумаем", "давайте сосредоточим усилия на..." "давайте назначим встречу на 14:00".

Comment: Тут же такой момент, автор указывает, что конструкция была использована в сочинении, какая прокуратура? там это т. н. "научное мы" - автор с читателем...

Answer (score 3):

Думаю, что учитель имеет в виду не грамматическую ошибку,а стилистическую. Лингвистическое сочинение на ОГЭ предполагает создание текста в **научном** стиле.Рассуждение строится по плану: тезис-доказательство-аргументы-вывод.

Доказательство характеризуется использованием типического набора средств. К стереотипным способам его оформления относится обозначение последовательности операций с помощью глаголов 1-го лица множественного числа: найдем, умножим, приравняем, определим и т. п. Результат этих операций вводится словами будет, будем иметь, получим, откуда получается, отсюда вытекает, тогда и др.

Повелительное наклонение используется в **публицистическом** стиле в побудительных конструкциях, а цель научного стиля не побуждение, а сообщение новых знаний,доказательство их истинности.

А насчёт разговорности, видимо, имелось в виду то, что побудительные конструкции используются в личном общении, разговоре. Частица "давайте","давай" является разговорной в других значениях:

2. разг. призыв к отдаванию чего-либо ◆ А ну давай мне конфеты!
3. разг. слово прощания ◆ Ну, давай, пока!
4. разг. закрепление договорённости ◆ Ладно, давай, я согласен.
5. спорт. крик болельщиков, призывающий к победе ◆ Давай, Италия, вперёд!

Так что слова учителя вовсе не чушь.

Comment: Людмила, каким-таким научным стилем пишется ***сочинение***?

Comment: Ко всему прочему, прочитав в молодости уйму математических книг, впервые слышу, что "давайте" там неуместно. Авторы, видимо, тоже о том не догадываются.  Вот первое попавшееся:  ----- *Заметим, что функция в данном примере может быть представлена в явном виде:.... формула.... **Давайте** ее продифференцируем и проверим результат, полученный выше.* -------------  http://www.cleverstudents.ru/derivative/implicit_function_derivative.html  Или Вы научным стилем что-то другое называете?!

Comment: "Каким-таким научным стилем пишется сочинение?"– Обычным научным..behemothus,, ученик знает, а Вам пишу: задание 15.1 в ОГЭ гласит: "Напишите сочинение-рассуждение, раскрывая смысл высказывания.Аргументируя ответ, приведите 2 примера из прочитанного текста.Вы можете написать работу в научном или публицистическом стиле..". И уж если выбрали научный, будьте добры его придерживаться. В Вашем примере не сочинение-рассуждение, там, скорее, лекция. Лекция - это общение с учеником, там побуждение уместно, в соч.-рассуждении нет.

Comment: Если бы это было сочинение-рассуждение в публицистическом стиле, ученик мог бы написать:"Давайте посмотрим, что хотел сказать автор этими словами.Почему, ..." Но если он собирается доказывать истинность высказывания, это научный стиль и никаких "давайте " там быть не может, это стилистическая ошибка.

Comment: *в научном или публицистическом стиле* - я начинаю думать, что схожу с ума. А что они понимают под научным стилем сочинения? И чем он отличается в таком случае от публицистики? Не поленюсь, прочитаю, если дадите ссылку. Я вот вам привел образец того, что я понимаю под научным стилем. И там, кстати, вполне уместное "давайте". Для меня "научный стиль", если на пальцах объяснять, это стиль, рассчитанный на логическое восприятие, эмоциональное сведено к минимуму. А наличие в тектсе слово "доказательство" для меня ровным счетом ничего не говорит.

Comment: Вне математической среды "доказать" это часто (увы!) означает "убедить", а то у вовсе "показать". А эти вещи имеют мало общего с научным стилем.  Я так и понимаю автора сочинения, он что-то там хочет "доказать" на примере, на убеждении... Разве вообще можно что-то *научно* "доказать" обратившись к чему-то? Это убеждение, не доказательство. Как все семь доказательств существования Бога, например. )))  Я не против использования такого приема, только не надо говорить, что это "научный" стиль. А вот слово "давайте" - ну никак научному стили не помеха.

Answer (score 1):

*Давай[те]* в словаре Кузнецова дано как разговорное. Так что в сочинении, особенно в сочинении-рассуждении, вполне можно посчитать за ошибку. Учитель прав.
Учитель не прав в одном — в том, что он начал перед вами оправдываться: мол, на семинаре сказали.

Comment: Употребление разговорного (по мнению Кузнецова) слова в сочинении - посчитать за ошибку? "Ну вы даете" (с).

Comment: Учитель, видимо, сам не понимает, что условному Кузнецову  не понравилось, поэтому и ссылается на семинар. Вместо того, чтобы честно признать, что никаких ошибок в этом слове нет.

Comment: Вы должны знать, что "разг." -- это не ругательство. )) Верно? Чисто в слове ошибок нет, а вы отличаете ошибки в слове от стилистических ошибок в сочинении? Вот, к примеру, в деловом стиле "давайте" применимо?

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что это стилистическая ошибка, такая форма обращения не очень уместна для научного стиля .

Сравним два варианта:

1) Научный стиль: Истинность данного высказывания **можно доказать**, обратившись к представленному тексту.

2) Разговорный стиль: Какие первые впечатления у вас, ребята, от рассказа «Матрёнин двор»?. А теперь **давайте найдём** начало действия, завязку сюжета.

Comment: Там нет научного стиля. Это сочинение.  Да и не о том речь, признали ошибкой не стиль, а одно слово.

Comment: А сочинение разве не имеет стилевую характеристику?  Что касается  "давайте",  то я хотела сказать, что именно это слово не подходит для научного стиля. Из словаря: Давай(те), в зн. частицы. (с инф. нсв. или с 1 л. мн. ч. буд. вр.). Разг. 1. Выражает приглашение к совместному действию или побуждение к действию.

Comment: *А сочинение разве не имеет стилевую характеристику?* - я не знаю, что вы сейчас понимаете под "стилевой характеристикой". Я знаю, что сочинение (да еще сочинение-рассуждение!) это все-таки эссе, очерк, ну фельетон... Публицистика.  "Научное сочинение" - это нечто совершенно другое...

Comment: Сложная тема... Сейчас говорят о жанрах и о стилях школьных сочинений, например: "Школьное сочинение — это тоже научная работа, только работа ученическая. Сочинения бывают разных жанров, и написать сочинение вне определения какого-либо жанра невозможно.  Жанры школьных сочинений: 1)   дневник; 2)    литературно-критическая статья; 3)    очерк; 4)    путешествие; 5)    рецензия; 6)    эпистолярный жанр (письмо); 7)    эссе. Стиль может быть близок к художественному,  научному, содержать элементы публицистики и т.д.

Comment: А научный-то кто из них?

Comment: А вообще не в этом даже дело. Вот систематика, под которой я готов подписаться. http://media.utmn.ru/library_view_book.php?bid=1371&chapter_num=17 здесь прямым тестом:  ***[в стиле очерка] существует три основных типа авторского повествования.... 3.  Повествование от первого лица множественного числа. Такой повествовательный тип ... может использоваться в наукообразных очерках.***  Я категорически не понимаю, почему научному стилю отказывают в праве использования этого приема, сотни лет  верой и правдой ему служившего...

Comment: В каждом жанре изначально строится особая авторская позиция и определяются отношения автора с читателем. Возможно,  выражение "давайте докажем" не вписывалось в общую картину таких отношений. Возможно, там был уместен более строгий и менее эмоциональный тип диалога. Вся приведенная лексика (докажем истинность данного высказывания, обратившись к представленному тексту) явно соответствует научному стилю, а для этого стиля, как мне кажется, более походят безличные предложения (можно доказать, а не давайте докажем).

Comment: *Возможно, выражение "давайте докажем" не вписывалось в общую картину таких отношений.* -??? Послушайте, ну куда разговор-то ушел...Топикстартер говорит о том, что не понравилось одно слово - потому что оно разговорное. Вы выдвигаете теорию, что сочинение написано "научным стилем" и потому-де, там слово неуместно. *Я прошу обосновать, a) с чего вдруг в школьном cочинении научный стиль прорезался и б) чем это слово не подходит для научного стиля*. И что вы мне в ответ кидаете? *Что слово-де не вписывалось в тот стиль, само наличие которого в школьном сочинении я прошу обосновать?!*

Comment: Я столько не выпью.

Comment: Тогда лучше вообще обойтись безо всяких частных оценок и определений и сказать, что в предложении «Давайте докажем //истинность данного высказывания» присутствует  стилевое несоответствие между лексикой, характерной для научных трактатов, и свободным обращением автора к читателю, обычно для произведений такого рода нехарактерным. Также, используя это обращение в различных ситуациях,   не будем забывать о том, что  в словаре на слове  "давайте" стоит стилевая пометка "разг."

Answer (score 0):

Да что можно сказать, не имея сколько-нибудь достаточной информации?

В той формулировке, как вы представили ("на семинаре сказали"), это действительно чушь полнейшая. Но подозреваю, что Вы его не поняли или неточно передали. Нужно точно знать, что именно "сказали на семинаре". Тогда и можно будет оценить.

Во фразе с "давайте" никаких лексических и/или стилистических ошибок не вижу. Да, такого построение фразы, возможно, не пойдет для официальной дипломатической переписки, там свои законы, ну так это не исключает использование его во всех других сферах.
(+)
Возможно ему не понравилось  "давайте" в сочетании с деепричастием совершенного вида? Если так, то отчасти могу согласиться, тяжеловесно. Но - только отчасти, ибо это не школьный уровень понимания стилистики, а грамматика никак не нарушена.
(++)
Еще одно предположение. Есть некоторые нелюбители использования первого лица множественного числа в текстах, обращенных у читателю (типа "продифференцируем эф от икс по икс", "рассмотрим поведение популяции кроликов" или там "Убедимся, что Пушкин первоначально назвал Зурина Гриневым, а Гринева - Булганиным"). Для таких авторов, "давайте", конечно, как красная тряпка. Сразу кричат что-нибудь насчет "говори за себя".

Но я совершенно не разделяю такое отношение к "научному мы". Неприлично говорить "мы считаем", имея в виду себя и читателя, который отнюдь не склонен считать то же, что и автор, это да. А "давайте-то" чем не угодило?

А вообще, Tangrix, лишний повод напомнить, что контекст вопроса надо давать максимально подробно. Ну что гадать-то, что там учителю в голову взбрело?!

Comment: Я же в посте вроде бы сказал, что ей не понравилось только слово, остальное нормально.

Comment: @Tagirix *"Только слово"* - нормальное, это даже не обсуждается. Уточните у неё ситуацию. Мало ли что кому не понравилось.

Comment: Зря вы гадаете. Нормальное слово.

Comment: @Morkovkin да может и зря. Мы тут копья ломаем, а автору судя по всему это не очень интересно, прокукарекал - а там хоть не рассветай, контекст так и не дал.

Comment: Я вам дал предложение, чего еще нужно-то?

Comment: @Tagirix Мне? Ничего. А вам надо бы дать контекст и более подробно мысль учительницы. Думаю, не одному мне интересно посмотреть на этот "научный" (по мнению Людмилы) стиль.

Answer (score 0):

Я не понимаю, что с этим словом не так и не разделяю мнения, что слово разговорное.

Tangrix, и все-таки как охарактеризовал учитель слово "Давайте"?
Если "неправильное" - то это личное мнение учителя или "семинариста".
"Разговорное" готов обсуждать, хотя тоже в том крепко сомневаюсь

Answer (score 0):

> Им где-то там на семинаре сказали, что это надо считать за ошибку.
>   То есть у неё из всех обоснований ссылка на то, что где-то так сказали.
>   Считаю это чушью, но никак не могу доказать.
>   Трудно доказать что-то тому, для кого аргументом является "где-то сказанное".

Ну, а раз на семинаре сказали, то и я скажу. Давайте, это побудительная частица (пруф: http://www.gumer.info/bibliotek_Buks/Linguist/DicTermin/n.php ) как бы побуждение слушателя/читателя к чему-то. Второе лицо. Вполне употребимо, если автор ведёт (как бы) диалог с читателем, такие тексты тоже бывают.

Answer (score 0):

Учитель русского языка утверждает,  что писать «Давайте докажем истинность данного высказывания,
 обратившись к представленному тексту» неправильно (конкретно — слово «давайте»).  Я не согласна с этим.
        Повелительное наклонение глагола 
обозначает действие как просьбу, приказ, 
побуждение к действию; образуется в том числе 
и с помощью частиц ПУСТЬ, ПУСКАЙ, ДА, ДАВАЙ, ДАВАЙТЕ.
 Следовательно, мы имеем дело с "нормальной" формообразующей частицей, образующей(простите за тавтологию)повелительное наклонение глагола ("давайте докажем").            Кроме того, сочинение 15.1 (на лингвистическую тему)при всей логичности, доказательности, аргументированности и композиционной стройности вряд ли строится строго в научном стиле. Простите, но уровень лингвистической подготовки наших учеников оставляет желать лучшего.Поэтому и сочинение дети пишут, скорее, не в научном, а в научно - популярном стиле. А там вполне допустимо использование данного "давайте докажем". Насколько я помню, и рассуждение в такой работе строится от первого лица множественного числа (местоимение"мы" - "давайте"). Согласна с Людмилой в том плане, что "результат ...рассуждений... вводится словами будет, будем иметь, получим, откуда получается, отсюда вытекает, тогда и др." Мне кажется, сюда хорошо вписываются "давайте предположим" и "давайте докажем"и т.д.
Извините, Людмила, но в первом примере "А ну давай мне конфеты!" - "давай" - это не частица, а форма глагола "давать" (повелительное наклонение).

С дальнейшим утверждением я абсолютно согласна.
 "Частица "давайте","давай" является разговорной в других значениях:
разг. слово прощания ◆ Ну, давай, пока!
разг. закрепление договорённости ◆ Ладно, давай, я согласен.
спорт. крик болельщиков, призывающий к победе ◆ Давай, Италия, вперёд!"
Возможно, действительно учитель возражала против необоснованного употребления   частицы "давай" в разговорных, просторечных и стилистически сниженных конструкциях.